# Nothing coming as output after starting a session in PHP

Tags: php

Below is my code:

```
<? php  
session_start();  
$_SESSION['view']=1;  
?>  
<html>  
<body>  
<?php  
//retrieve session data  
echo "Pageviews=".isset($_SESSION['views']);  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Expected answer for below code is `Pageviews=1` but I am getting as `Pageviews=`.
Please assist as I am new to PHP.

Comment: It should be $_SESSION['view'] instead of $_SESSION['views'] .. The session name is "view" not "views"

Comment: Please pay attention to the way you've spelled `view` each time you use it.

Comment: remove space between `<?` and `php`should be removed

Comment: Thanks all for the help today!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

`isset` returns only true or false. It will not output anything. Do this:

`echo "Pageviews=".$_SESSION['view'];`

Comment: This is false. It will return a boolean value, which, when `true` will be casted to a string as `1`. From the docs: `A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check session name and Remove isset

try it :

```
<? php  
session_start();  
$_SESSION['view']=1;  
?>  
<html>  
<body>  
<?php  
//retrieve session data  
echo "Pageviews=".$_SESSION['view'];  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Isset is used to determine whether the variable is set or not. It returns true/false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
<?php  
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['view']=1;  
?>  
<html>  
<body>  
<?php  
    //retrieve session data  
    if(isset($_SESSION['view']))
       echo "Pageviews=".$_SESSION['view'];  

?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: as noted by @Bjørne Malmanger, space between `<?` and `php` should be removed

Comment: so like it , uprate it, just click the right arrow and up arrow on the left side of the post to say thanks